# How can I reduce exponents in a field with modulo 7?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If I was working in a polynomial field with class of congruence to mod 7, so [0], [1], … , [6], and I wanted to reduce my exponents, for example if I had [2]x^103, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Use Fermat's little theorem: $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$ for $p$ prime.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why are you answering in a comment?